# How to choose function names?

Tags: javascript, function, naming-conventions, naming

We're having a discussion at work, because of my tendency to name functions based on what they do.

For instance:

```
function notifyUserOfSomeThingThatHappened(){
    // notification code
}
```

My coworker believes (and I kind of agree) that this function should be named based on why it's being called, rather than what it does, since what it does could change.

Something like this:

```
function someThingHappened(){
    // notification code
    // possible new code in the future
}
```

I agree with this, but with a catch: I think we should name functions that will only ever do one thing by their actual contents, but other functions by their reason for being called, like this:

```
function someThingHappened(){
    notifyUserThatSomeThingHappened();
    // possible new code in the future
}

function notifyUserThatSomeThingHappened(){
    // original code
}
```

What are the best practices for naming functions? Why are these practices used? What are the advantages of one over the other?

Comment: I would have to go with `function someThingHappened(){
    notifyUserThatSomeThingHappened();
    // possible new code in the future
}` because it will let you reuse the `somethinghappened()` function for more than one situation without needing to add much more code.

Comment: I found duplicates and this should probably be closed to be honest.

Comment: i wouldn't say opinion-based, since I'm asking for explanations and comparisons. Without a reason, it shouldn't be here.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

A simple rule is:
 
Function names should be verbs if the function **changes** the state of the program, and nouns if they're used to **return** a certain value.

Another thing to keep in mind is **consistency**.

If you use the name `getName` be consistent and don't write somewhere else `retrieveName` as this might confuse your co-workers.

Also keep in mind that different languages do indeed have different name conventions so you should always check what is the best way to name `functions` and `variables` in the language you're working with.

Comment: I'll wait for more answers before I mark this as best answer, just in case.